# Mass mail 50k + users, solution?

Tags: emails, joomla-3.6

As the title suggests, I have a pretty large user base, pushing 60k now, and I can never mass mail them, I cant even do batch functions as joomla (or rather my server) runs out of memory when trying to query the database of that many users.

Is there a solution for mass mailing so many users that takes into account that not everybody's server has 16+GB ram free for PHP to load the entire user table into memory?

Comment: Why not go with a 3rd party mass email distribution service?

Comment: +1 for using a commercial service. Why do you think these services exist? It's because they reliably deliver email to a large number of users for a very, very low cost. Far lower than you can hope to do it, reliably, from your own (shared?) server.

Comment: We are a donation run organization and want to cut costs by using hardware that we already have. Our hosting plan allows for unlimited outbound emails per hour so figure we would use what we are already paying for.

Comment: You're out of luck. There is no way you'll be able to send an email that even 5% of those 60k will receive unless you use a commercial service. And even then you'll have trouble getting your email to the recipients.

Comment: I don't think you are doing your donors any favours by sending 60k emails from your server, of which not many will never arrive, at least at the 2nd email out. Is your objective to send 60k emails or for them to be received?

Comment: Why wouldn't they be received? I already use my servers SMTP for account verification, password resets, support... Why would I pay somebody else to send email.

Comment: There is plenty of reason: lack of DKIM, accidental virus on your network etc etc

Comment: We already have DKIM, and how in the world would this open me up to viruses any more than we already are?

Comment: As others have hinted at, Joomla! is not a mass mailing utility, despite what the title of that Joomla! core component is named. It is a CMS for websites. You can make it do a whole lot more, but only with 3rd party extensions and services.

Comment: @MichaelYaeger You aren't telling me anything I dont already know.

Comment: "Why would I pay somebody else to send email." - @wobbles.... Because, the tools/setup you currently have won't work (hence, why you are here asking the question).

Comment: @MichaelYaeger Then recommend a tool.... Don't just tell me to pay somebody else to do it, thats a lazy answer.

Answer (score 4):

The most common solution is AcyMailing + a professional SMTP service.

AcyMailing is the best mailing extension for Joomla.

My favorites SMTP services are SendGrid and Postmark. I also implement Amazon SES sometimes.

Alternatively, I know people implementing Mandrill.

All of these solutions are for newsletters and regular notifications. Obviously, spam is not tolerated.

PD: I avoid Mailchimp, too expensive.

Comment: So i've already used AcyMailing, but since it does not seem to handle batch mails using BCC, it is horribly slow... Any suggestions about this?

Comment: I think you can solve these issues in your server. It has enough juice to handle them.

Comment: @wobbles, in what way are you using BCC? What email address is going in that field and does it change?

Comment: @Anibal, as a note, [Mandrill](https://mandrill.com/) is [no longer available as a standalone SMTP service](http://blog.mandrill.com/important-changes-to-mandrill.html). It must be purchased as an [add-on to the MailChimp service](http://kb.mailchimp.com/mandrill/add-or-remove-mandrill).

Answer (score 2):

The Joomla! CMS is not a mass mailing utility and should not be used as such. Though there is a [Mass Mail component](https://docs.joomla.org/Help36:Users_Mass_Mail_Users) in the Joomla! core, Arvind Chauhan of [JoomlaArt](https://www.joomlart.com/) points out that "[It’s not ethical [or legal] to send promotional emails to users who have not opted-in to receive them.](https://www.joomlart.com/tutorials/joomla-tutorials/joomla-mass-mail-feature-explained)" The Mass Mail component does not have this *opt-in* feature.

---

### ACYmailing

As [@Anibal](https://joomla.stackexchange.com/users/174/anibal) [mentions](https://joomla.stackexchange.com/a/17855/5638), [ACYmailing](https://www.acyba.com/acymailing.html) is the most common and integrated solution for Joomla! for doing such. And, even though it is specific to Joomla!, it rivals the best 3rd party eNewsletter platforms available.

---

### 3rd Party Email Marketing Platforms

For a more universal approach and one that will work regardless of whether your on Joomla! or not, you can choose any number of [email marketing services](https://www.google.com/search?q=email%20marketing%20services). Since you are a non-profit looking to pinch every penny, there are several services that offer free non-profit accounts:

- [Benchmark](http://www.benchmarkemail.com/we-care-about-kids/sign-up) - 100,000 child-focused emails per month
- [Vertical Response](http://www.verticalresponse.com/pricing/non-profit/application) - 10,000 emails per month or 15% off
- [Campaigner](http://www.campaigner.com/free-for-non-profits/) - [contact](http://www.campaigner.com/about/contact/) for terms

---

### Email Hosting

If you already have a method for newsletter opt-in handling and simply need a beefy SMTP server for sending the emails, these services are free to non-profits:

- [Google Apps](https://www.google.com/nonprofits/products/apps-for-nonprofits.html) (G-Suite)
- [Microsoft Office 365](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/philanthropies/product-donations/products/office365nonprofit)
- [Amazon SES](http://www.techsoup.org/amazon-web-services)
- [MailTrap](https://mailtrap.io/pricing)

*Note: Please, confirm your intensions for using their services meet their terms of use prior to sending.*

---

### In-House Email Marketing Platform

If you already have a method for newsletter opt-in handling and you believe your current SMTP server is sufficient to handle the emailing duties, won't get your hosting account closed, won't get the server blacklisted, or won't cause messages to be flagged as SPAM, but you need a beefier app to handle the creation and management of your email marketing campaigns, try [G-Lock EasyMail7](http://www.glocksoft.com/easymail/). It is [free to non-profits](http://www.glocksoft.com/easymail/free-newsletter-software-for-non-profit-organizations/).

> With G-Lock EasyMail7 you can use your own hosts email system (SMTP) for FREE or enhance delivery with third party senders like [AMAZON SES](https://aws.amazon.com/ses/), that allow you to pay for what you use… Imagine being able to send 10,000 emails for just $1.